# Variable in directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

This does not seem possible, but is it:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in myitems | {{ searchfilter }}">
   <span>{{ item.title }}</span>
</div>
```

or some variant of it? All I get are no results.

Comment: why not just filter myitems first instead of evaluating it in expression?

Comment: what is `searchfilter` in scope? is it object, function name?

Comment: ABOS It's supposed to be used in another directive, for a certain type of list of items. dfsq for functionality like ordering and such.

Comment: can you post how you define `searchfilter` in controller?

Comment: for example, orderBy: 'name', orderBy 'date' and I can access the filter from the view directive as I write in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

`searchfilter` should not have `{{ }}` around it. Since this is a directive, angular knows how to deal with the variable. You only need the braces when trying to inject a variable from angular scope into the non-angular HTML.

Comment: I noticed that. Although, "orderBy" and "filter" works now with a variable. Where filters value is like { Show: true } (for example) or 'Date' as orderBy value. Except "track by" which is not working with a variable the same way.

Answer (score 0):

You should correct syntax to this instead:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in myitems | filter:searchfilter">
    With Search filter Moustaches :<span>{{ item.title }}</span>
  </div>
```

Have created a small plunk for reference.

http://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:rfqcl9AHEoJZEEJxyNn2?p=preview